# Get a list of categories per row using a MariaDb Select Subquery

Tags: mariadb

I am new to MariaDB,

I have a list os stores that are categorized by one or more categories.

I need to show a Json representation of this structure.

How can i, using Maria DB, get a list of categories in this format?

```
{
    store_name: "One Store",
    site_url: null,     
    categories: [
        {
            name: "Category 1",
            name: "Category 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

I try using a select subquery but the error message is : subquery returns more than onem row:

```
SELECT 
    store_name
    site_url     
    ( SELECT a.name 
        FROM  stores l, store_activity la, activities a 
        WHERE la.idloja = l.id 
        AND a.id = la.idactivity
    ) AS categories
FROM stores s, stores_activities la, activities a 
WHERE sa.idstore = s.id 
AND a.id = sa.idactivity;
```

This is my data modeling:

```
table : stores
id | name
1, One Store
2, Second Store

table : categories
id | name
1, Category 1
2, Category 2

table : store_activity
id | idactivity | idstore
1, 1, 1
1, 1, 2
2, 2, 1
```

Comment: Which version of MariaDB? There were quite a lot of [JSON functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/json-functions/) added for MariaDB 10.2 that could be useful for this. Or will you be using PHP/Java/Python or other such programming language to create the actual JSON?

Comment: Hi @dbdemon, the version is 10.2.9, i need just the array results, i will let the php handle the return.